# Generating labels and storing variables?

Tags: vb.net, instance-variables, label

So I generate 100 labels with the following:

```
Sub Load_Pieces()
    For i = 0 To 9
        For i1 = 0 To 9
            Pieces(i1, i) = New Label
            Pieces(i1, i).Text = ""
            Pieces(i1, i).Location = New Point((i1 * 20) + 13, (i * 20) + 13)

            Pieces(i1, i).Size = New Size(20, 20)
            Pieces(i1, i).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            Pieces(i1, i).Font = New Font("Arial", 13)
            Pieces(i1, i).BackColor = Color.White
            AddHandler Pieces(i1, i).Click, AddressOf Piece_Clicked
            Me.Controls.Add(Pieces(i1, i))
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

What I need to do is for the labels to hold three or four individual variables each(all integers), and for the `Piece_Clicked` function to be able to read the variables of both the piece that was clicked and of adjacent tiles(or any tile, for that matter).

**Example:** Piece 66 is clicked, it increases the number piece 65 is displaying by one, and displays the result on piece 67.

I figure that, among the other variables, the labels would need to be assigned identification numbers that would allow them to work out which labels are adjacent.
I also assume the labels themselves can't actually store variables, so would I need to use an array or dictionary that stores the numbers, and clicking a label accesses the corresponding array/dictionary entries?

Answer (score 0):

> I also assume the labels themselves can't actually store variables

A control can store any variable in the [`Tag` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx).

I'd recommend using a custom class to store these three variables and assign an instance of it to the `Tag` property. Cast it back to the type in `Piece_Clicked`.